# @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) how to lock only few rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a method like:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public default Student doSomething(Student student) {
  School sch = student.getSchool(); // @JoinColumn's
  List students = sch.getAllStudents();
  List names = getAllNames(students); // stream.map to names or something similar.
  if(!names.contains(student.name)) {
    save(student);
}
}
```

As we can see from the code snippet here we have a student. From the student we get the school and then all the students from that school. Then we get their names and if the student is not there we are adding it - otherwise not.
From that code I expect serializable exception only when 2 threads are adding for the same school. But I am having the "cant serialize access" even if we add students for 2 different schools. Isn't spring/hibernate locking mechanism dealing with such cases? :( Shouldn't it lock only the lines from the table that were used during the method? Please help on that specific case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How locking is done depends on the database. Some lock rows, some tables and some parts of the table. So it depends, there is no easy and one off answer that will help here. Also you have a `SERIALIZED` access but retrieve all students, so I guess regardless of what the database is doing you always lock all the students due to this.

Comment: you are wrong @M. Deinum ... I am getting all the students of this school, which are not all the students in the students table.

Comment: Looked like you where doing a repo call. Then it really depends on the database you are using how locking is implemented. If it is row, page, or table based. It also depends on the amount of data, etc. etc. So as stated earlier no easy answer.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough but imagine that there are many schools, and the students table is containing all the students for all the schools, but School::getAllStudents will return only the students for that school, not all the students.

Comment: Again how locking is implemented depends on the database you are using. Some use row locks other page and other use table locks. So as stated before there is no easy answer as it depends on your database.So go and read the documentation of your database server and how that is implementing the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but isn't the Isolation.SERIALIZABLE locking all tables and prevents you to add the student ?

Comment: in 21 century I hope not :D for sure it doesnt lock "all tables", but it should be locking even a whole table but just the rows I have used DML operations on.

Comment: Maybe it depend on your database. I see some (old) similare isues with Oracle :
http://www.oraclenerd.com/2009/02/ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for.html

Comment: this is the expected behaviour when an other thread modified the data you already read, but before the transaction is commit. But I am 'reading the data' only for 1 school- that means I am reading the data only for the students of that school and not for the shole students table. So I expect only few rows locked not all.

Comment: I suppose you have already read the school before the transaction begins and then added it to your new student.
When you save your student, can't this be interpreted as a modification of the school ? Knowing that the school object was created outside the current transaction.

Comment: Can you add your hibernate SQL logs please ?
Maybe it will help to understand.